# How to make this query happen

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

```
user
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
id        last_activity
500       8:00PM
100       7:00PM
200       2:00PM

institution
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
user_id        name
500            Harvard Institution

instructor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
user_id        job_title        fname        lname
100            Dr.              Alex         Adam

student
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
user_id        fname        lname        reg_code
200            Smith        Mark         RdT1v4dq

announcement
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
id        institution_id        title
900       500                   Announcement Title!

announcement_replay
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
announcement_id        user_id        content
900                    200            Hello, I'm student Smith
900                    100            Hello, I'm instructor Alex
900                    500            Hello, I'm Harvard Institution
```

In this schema how can i select the **name** of the **user** who posted the **announcement_replay**.

For example that what i want to get:

```
query result
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
announcement_id        institution        instructor        student        content
900                    null               null              Smith Mark     Hello, I'm student Smith
900                    null               Dr. Alex Adam     null           Hello, I'm instructor Alex
900                    Harvard            null              null           Hello, I'm Harvard Institution
```

So i can list them in a page through *php* and use null to determine what's the user type.

Also is this schema better?

```
institution: id, name;
    instructor: institution.id, job_title, fname, lname;
    student: institution.id, fname, lname, reg_code;
        ann: id, institution.id, title;
            ann_replay: id, ann.id, content;
                ann_replay_instructor: ann_replay.id, instructor.id;
                ann_replay_student: ann_replay.id, student.id;
```

Comment: Don't vandalise your posts for any reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ar.announcement_id,
  ins.name institution,
  concat(i.job_title,' ', i.fname, ' ', i.lname) instructor,
  concat(s.fname, ' ', s.lname) student,
  ar.content
FROM
  announcement_replay ar
LEFT OUTER JOIN student s
ON
  ar.user_id = s.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN instructor i
ON
  ar.user_id = i.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN institution ins
ON
  ar.user_id = ins.user_id;
```

I think this is ok (made a few changes):

```
institution: id, name;
instructor: instructor_id, job_title, fname, lname, institution.id;
student: student_id, fname, lname, reg_code, institution.id;
ann: id, institution.id, title;
ann_replay: id, ann.id, content;
ann_replay_instructor: ann_replay.id, instructor.id;
ann_replay_student: ann_replay.id, student.id;
```

Comment: Beat me to it!
This answer should be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: And which's better please the first schema or the second one (in speed)?

Comment: @IbrahimMuhammad Updated

Comment: So this is faster than creating a "user" table as main table? And if so, can you please tell me who to select to archive the same result on it?